# How to Change Mapping of only one field in elasticsearch (text to date) ? ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Just Sharing the work that worked for me, I have a index where one of the Date Field is indexed as "text", I need to change the mapping from "text" to "date", I did the following

Step 1: Create a New Index with the Field that need a change with new Mapping

```
PUT new_index {
    "mappings": {
          "doc": {
             "properties": {
                "Date_Field": { "type": "date", "format": "dd/MM/yyyy"}
             }
          }
     }
 }
```

Step 2: Reindex the old index to the created New Index

```
POST _reindex
{
   "source": {
     "index": "old_index"
    },

   "dest": {
      "index": "new_index"
    }
}
```

Only thing is new index is created,it worked for me

Comment: it would be great if you can tell clearly the exact issue?

Comment: mentioned that just sharing the work that worked for me, there is issue question here, its about changing mapping of specific field in elastic

Comment: I guess this is not a question, it is an answer directly. :)